# Text not centered between borders?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've uploaded a copy of the page you can see here:

http://cybercacher.com/test123/tabs/

Scroll down the page a bit and you'll see that the header sticks to the top.  Whenever you hover over any of the options at the top, you'll notice that there's more space between the text and border at the top in comparison to the bottom.

NOTE:  You have to scroll down the page a bit to see what I'm talking about, it's working properly already with the default (non-sticky) header.

I've searched for any padding or margins that could be causing this but can't seem to figure out what's causing this to happen...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your site is completely unusable. I can't hover the elements because when I move the mouse, the page scrolls. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "you'll notice that there's more space between the text and border at the top in comparison to the bottom." What are you referring to? Top of what? bottom of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sticky-nav ul li a:hover {
    height: 35px !important;
    line-height: 31px !important; /* change this */
```

You'll need to apply the same to the non-hover state to prevent a jump:

```
#sticky-nav ul li a {
    ...
    line-height: 31px !important;
```

Consider reconfiguring to this so that the borders persist when the user is inside the dropdown menu:

```
#sticky-nav ul > li:hover > a {
```